# check internet reachable or not in china

Tags: android, ios, react-native, reachability, great-firewall-of-china

I need to check if internet accessible from the mobile or not in order to show a different view in my app.

My app is in react-native and I am using the plugin `react-native-netinfo` for this. but this plugin pings google for checking the connectivity.
As Google is blocked in china I am getting is not connected though connected to internet. Is there any other site instead of `http://google.com/generate_204`

I can set the site name using the options provided:

```
NetInfo.configure({
            reachabilityUrl: 'http://google.com/generate_204',
            reachabilityTest: async response => response.status === 200,
            reachabilityLongTimeout: 60 * 1000, // 60s
            reachabilityShortTimeout: 50 * 1000, // 5s
            reachabilityRequestTimeout: 15 * 1000, // 15s
        });
```

I have tried using `GitHub.com` that's also now blocked in China. Is there any reliable site that I can use for long term as well specially for China?

Note: can check whether site usable in china or not using: `http://www.chinafirewalltest.com`

Comment: why does your app need the internet? why not check if the services the app needs are accessible?

Comment: I have mentioned it in the first, that I need to display a new view if app is offline. so I need constantly look for internet connectivity. if there is any public reliable site it will be helpful else exposing a public endpoint from my api's is risky.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [www.baidu.com](http://www.baidu.com) which is the search engine in China.

But this is not "Internet reachable", it is "site reachable". Even if [www.baidu.com](http://www.baidu.com) is reachable, it does not mean your target site is reachable.

Comment: if we reach directly Baidu.com it will big html in return. if we are checking for more no of times it may treat as a bot attack and block. So, having some service which simply return status 204 is the best one to use, does Baidu has a generate_204 like google?